# View State lost with click

Tags: android, view, onclick, state

I have created a custom View that is essentially a Gallery object that can be hidden and shown (using View.VISIBLE and View.GONE) by clicking on a TextView.

The images I place in this gallery have a custom background StateListDrawable selector.  Everything works fine except the state of the images in the gallery seems to get lost when the gallery goes from View.GONE to View.VISIBLE, and that the selector that is drawn is the default drawable (translucent_box).

These are the items in my selector XML:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_box" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/orange_box" android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_box" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/translucent_box" />
```

The strangest thing is that after returning from a call to startActivity, the state gets restored and everything displays fine until I hide and show the gallery again.

I have tried playing around with adding different states in the selector and programmatically trying to refresh the view... to no avail.

Any ideas?  I'm sure it has got to be something trivial...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you get the focused/selected view when your widget is visible, save it and re-apply it when you return to the visible state?

Comment: I had played around with trying to do that but to no avail... hence the reason for the question.  Also, from what I could tell, there is a way to set the selected state but not the focused state...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround for my case.  I'm not sure it is the best way and I still don't know what is causing the behavior, but I was able to get what I wanted by calling notifyDataSetChanged() on my gallery's adapter.

If anyone has a better suggestion on how to solve the problem (mine seems like it might be a little overkill) or even a description of why this is happening, I would appreciate it... I am very curious about what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's relevant - but do you need to implement View.verifyDrawable?  The docs aren't very clear as to when you need to do that.

startActivity will trigger an animation by default - which is probably what is forcing the view to refresh correctly.  Another possible hack around this would be to trigger an empty animation of some sort.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but after overriding that method I stepped throught the debugger and that method never called.